# Working MySQL Query hogging CPU time

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search

I have a working SQL query that when running, takes up to 3 mins to run and cranks the mysqld service to over 100% usage.
I am needing to do a full text search on 3 different tables.
I need a better way to do this that is not only quicker but does not take the sql service to 100% which in turn, kills the web site it drives. 
I'm performing these tests on an Ubuntu linux box but the production version will be running on a Enterprise version of Redhat linux.

here is the query

```
SET @data = 'insert search text here';
SELECT * FROM stock
    LEFT JOIN options ON options.stock_no = stock.stock_no
    LEFT JOIN udesc ON udesc.stock_no = stock.stock_no
WHERE
    (MATCH (stock.stock_no, stock.year, stock.mfg, stock.brand, stock.model, stock.type, stock.dsgn, stock.fptype, stock.chassis_no, stock.int_colour, stock.lbrand, stock.tagwords) AGAINST (@data IN BOOLEAN MODE))
    OR
    (MATCH (options.title) AGAINST (@data IN BOOLEAN MODE))
    OR
    (MATCH (udesc.data) AGAINST (@data IN BOOLEAN MODE))
AND stock.type NOT LIKE 'other'
ORDER BY STATUS ASC;
```

Anyone have an idea how I  can restructure this to where it not only performs the search fast but doesn't take up 100% of the CPU time on the mysqld service, killing the web site? I can provide further table data if needed.
yes, all of the tables are fulltext indexed. As I said, this is a WORKING query.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Run an Explain before the SELECT and let us see the output.

Comment: Are your tables indexed *at all*?

Comment: We'll see in the explain ^^

Comment: prior to running this query I listed all affected fields in fulltext indexes using the following commands:
`ALTER TABLE stock ADD FULLTEXT stk(stock_no, year, mfg, brand, model, type, dsgn, fptype, chassis_no, int_colour, lbrand, tagwords); 
ALTER TABLE options ADD FULLTEXT opt(title);
ALTER TABLE udesc ADD FULLTEXT dsc(data;`'

Comment: here is the explain... it was dumped as a CSV so sorry about the formatting:  

`id select_type table type possible_keys key key_len ref rows Extra 1 SIMPLE stock ALL NULL NULL NULL NULL 1936 Using temporary; Using filesort 1 SIMPLE options ALL NULL NULL NULL NULL 11992 Using where 1 SIMPLE udesc eq_ref PRIMARY PRIMARY 50 inventory.stock.STOCK_NO 1 Usi‌​ng where`

I'll see if there is a better way to post this

Comment: Next time instead of three comments you should edit your original post and add these details there

Comment: I ran out of room with the limited number of characters. And this editor isn't the best in the world but it's functionable.

Comment: well, I tried to post a version of the Explain done from the Command line method instead of using the MySQL workbench and I get killed because it says that it's over the character limit.
at least I tried.  :-(

Comment: how about this link to the explain analizer--> [link](http://tools.mariadb.org/ea/r7swc)